# How to add already created records to collection in sails.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I'm creating sails App with two models one-to-many realationship.

### Person.js

```
module.exports = {

 types: {

         uniqueEmail:function(value) {
  return uniqueEmail;         
       },
   password: function(password) {
  return password === this.passwordConfirmation;
       }
   },
     schema:true,

      attributes: {

  firstname: {
        alpha:true,
        required: true
      },
  lastname:{
       alpha:true,
       required: true

  },

  username:{
      type:'string',

      unique: true,

      required:true

  },
  password:{

       type:'string',
        required:true,
        password:true

    },
  age:{
      numeric:true,
       required: true
      },
  gender:{
       alpha:true,
       required: true


  },
  email:{

      type:'email',
      required: true,
      unique:true,
      uniqueEmail:true

  },

  passwordConfirmation: {
  type: 'string'
  },

  department:{
        model: 'Department',
         required: true

    },

  qualifications:{

        collection: 'Qualification',
        via: 'person'

  },

  loggedIn: {
  type: 'boolean',
  defaultsTo: 0,
  required: true
}
```

},

### qualification.js

```
    module.exports = {

       attributes: {


  qualificationName:{

      required:true,
      alpha:true,



  },

  qualificationDesc:{

       required:true,
      alpha:true

      },

  person:{
        model:'Person'
    }

    },
```

I've created the Qualification separately

```
Qualification.create({qualificationName:req.param('qualificationName'),qualificationDesc:req.param('description')}).exec(function createCB(err, created){

        });
```

Now I need to add this qualification to my Person model.

As per sails documentation I'd like to add like this

```
    Person.find({name:'Mike'}).populate('qualifications').exec(function(e,r){
        r[0].qualifications.add(7);
       r[0].save(function(err,res){
        console.log(res);
            }
             });
```

But the problem is 'add(7)' I'm trying to add mongodb id in add method How to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.